# Построить дерево из массива

Tags: php

Дан массив вида

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
    [3] => 7
    [4] => 5
)
```

Нужно получить массив:

```
Array(
    [1] => [2] => [3] => 7
    [4] => 5
)
```

То есть если уже существует значение в массиве, то он превращается ещё один массив.

Comment: Ваши попытки?
Тут помогают, а не просто решают задачки за вас :)

Comment: @Daniil, спасибо за замечание. Я не стал приводить примеры своих решений, так как они задачу не решали даже близко.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$arr = [
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3,
    3 => 7,
    4 => 5
];

function format(&$arr) {
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        if ( !is_array($value) && !empty($arr[$value]) ) {
            $arr[$key] = [array_search($arr[$value], $arr) => $arr[$value]];
            unset($arr[$value]);
            format($arr);
            break;
        } else if ( is_array($value)) {
            // берём значение с вложенного массива
            array_walk_recursive($value, function ($item, $key) use (&$val){$val = $item;});
            if ( !empty($arr[$val]) ) {
                $arrVal = [array_search($arr[$val], $arr) => $arr[$val]];
                // кладём новое значение во вложенный массив
                array_walk_recursive($value, function (&$item, $key) use ($arrVal){$item = $arrVal;});
                $arr[$key] = $value;
                unset($arr[$val]);
                format($arr);
                break;
            }
            
        }
    }
}

format($arr);

var_dump($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr = ["1" => "2", "2" => "3", "4" => "5", "5" => "6", "7" => "8"];

foreach ($arr as $keyff => $valueff) {
    $si = array_keys($arr);
    foreach ($si as $keyz => $valuez) {
        if( $valuez == $valueff ){
            $arr[$valuez-1] = [$valuez => $arr[$valuez]];
            unset($arr[$valuez]);
        }
    }
}

echo "<br>";
print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Спасибо за предложенное решение. Но данный метод ломается при усложнение массива.

Comment: @Jeix так вы изначально приведите пример с "усложненным" массивом, чтобы нюансы видно было сразу.

Comment: @teran более сложный пример есть в вопросе и данный ответ для него не корректно работает

Answer (score 0):

Так как в ходе работы задача значительно усложнилась, получился вот такое решение:

```
class Finder {
    public function array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $haystack) {
        foreach($haystack as $first_level_key=>$value) {
            if ($needle === $value) {
                return array($first_level_key);
            } elseif (is_array($value)) {
                $callback = $this->array_recursive_search_key_map($needle, $value);
                if ($callback) {
                    return array_merge(array($first_level_key), $callback);
                }
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    public function get($list) {
        $filter = [];
        foreach ($list as $X => $Y) {
            $i = $this->array_recursive_search_key_map($X, $list);
            if ($i !== false) {
                $keymap = $this->array_recursive_search_key_map($X, $filter);
                if ($keymap !== false) {
                    $nest_depth = sizeof($keymap)-1;
                    if (isset($keymap[3])) {
                        $filter[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]][$keymap[3]] = [$X, [$Y]];
                    } else if (isset($keymap[2])) {
                        $filter[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]][$keymap[2]] = [$X, [$Y]];
                    } else if (isset($keymap[1])) {
                        $filter[$keymap[0]][$keymap[1]] = [$X, [$Y]];
                    } else {
                        $filter[] = [$X, [$Y]];
                    }
                }
            } else {
                if(array_search($X, $filter) == false) $filter[] = [$X, [$Y]];
            }
        }

        return $filter;
    }
}
```

Если функции передать массив

```
Array(
    [109] => 110
    [110] => 111
    [265] => [266, 268]
    [266] => 267
    [268] => 269
)
```

Будет результат:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(109)
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(110)
        [1]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          int(111)
        }
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    int(265)
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(266)
          [1]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            int(267)
          }
        }
        [1]=>
        array(2) {
          [0]=>
          int(268)
          [1]=>
          array(1) {
            [0]=>
            int(269)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```